# MigLayout - componentResized() called too many times

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I have the following scenario - I have a panel which holds a component (label in this case) within another panel - all defined with `MigLayout`.

When the panel is resized, I want to adjust the size of the font of the `JLabel` in such way to fit the whole area.

I stripped the code to the bare minimum

```
public class TestClass {

    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel displayLabel;

    private TestClass() {
        panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout(new LC().fill().gridGap("0", "0").insetsAll("0").hideMode(3)));

        displayLabel = new JLabel("some text goes here");
        displayLabel.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 9));
        panel.add(displayLabel, new CC().grow().push());

        panel.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                scale(displayLabel);
            }
        });
    }

    private void scale(JLabel component) {
        Integer lastWidth = (Integer) component.getClientProperty("width");
        Integer lastHeight = (Integer) component.getClientProperty("height");
        if (lastWidth != null && lastHeight != null && lastWidth == component.getWidth() && lastHeight == component.getHeight()) {
            return;
        }

        component.putClientProperty("width", component.getWidth());
        component.putClientProperty("height", component.getHeight());

        int minFontSize = 9;
        Font oldFont = component.getFont();
        float size = oldFont.getSize();
        Font newFont = oldFont.deriveFont(size);
        FontMetrics fm = component.getFontMetrics(newFont);

        int availWidth = component.getWidth() - 2;
        int availHeight = component.getHeight() - 2;

        boolean found = false;
        boolean increased = false;
        boolean decreased = false;
        while (!found) {
            int stringWidth = fm.stringWidth(component.getText());
            int stringHeight = fm.getHeight();
            if (!decreased && stringWidth < availWidth && stringHeight < availHeight) {
                size++;
                increased = true;
            } else if (stringWidth > availWidth || stringHeight > availHeight) {
                size--;
                decreased = true;
            } else {
                found = true;
            }
            if (increased && decreased) {
                found = true;
            }
            newFont = oldFont.deriveFont(size);
            fm = component.getFontMetrics(newFont);
        }

        if (size < minFontSize) {
            size = minFontSize;
            newFont = oldFont.deriveFont(size);
        }

        component.setFont(newFont);
    }


    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new MigLayout(new LC().fill()));
        pnl.add(new TestClass().getPanel(), new CC().grow().push());
        frame.add(pnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(1024, 700);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

When I resize the frame by dragging the right edge to enlarge it - it works just fine, however, when I try to decrease its size, by dragging left of the right edge, the application is sluggish and the result is not reflected immediately in the GUI. Please run it in order to see what I mean.

Do you have any idea how I can improve this code in order to work smooth?

### [image]

**Update**: I've added some logging and I've observed that when increasing the width it works fine, but when decreasing the width of the panel I see the componentResized() method is called many more times compared to when enlarging it.

The cause of the problem seems to be the MigLayout in combination with grow(). I've replaced all the layouts with BorderLayout and seems to work fine.

However, I can't really do that in my case, since I need my panel to grow in my layout.

Comment: I tried this out, thinking "well, that cannot be sooo hard to fix", but ... yeah, well. It *seems* to me that MigLayout internally does some sort of "wiggling" of the component sizes: Wenn the component becomes smaller, it tries to "iteratively" adjust the sizes of all contained components until it sits and fits. But I haven't found a way to prevent this. (I'll still have to check the minimum size solution that you proposed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but it seems that setting a minimum size to the JLabel will solve the problem.

```
private TestClass() {
    panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout(new LC().fill().gridGap("0", "0").insetsAll("0").hideMode(3)));

    displayLabel = new JLabel("some text goes here");
    displayLabel.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 9));
    displayLabel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(30, 10));
    panel.add(displayLabel, new CC().grow().push());

    panel.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            scale(displayLabel);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the method is called multiple times try to calculate the value only once. You can store last computed width & height in component and calculate the size when one of these values changed:

```
private void scale(JLabel component) {
    int minFontSize = 9;
    float size = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    size = Math.min(size, component.getWidth());
    size = Math.min(size, component.getHeight());

    Integer lastWidth = (Integer) component.getClientProperty("width");
    Integer lastHeight = (Integer) component.getClientProperty("height");
    if (lastWidth != null && lastHeight != null && lastWidth.intValue() == component.getWidth() && lastHeight.intValue() == component.getHeight()) {
        return;
    }

    component.putClientProperty("width", component.getWidth());
    component.putClientProperty("height", component.getHeight());

    component.putClientProperty("lastSize", new Integer((int) size));

    Font oldFont = component.getFont();
    Font newFont = oldFont.deriveFont(size);
    FontMetrics fm = component.getFontMetrics(newFont);

    int availWidth = component.getWidth() - 2;
    int availHeight = component.getHeight() - 2;

    while ((size > minFontSize) && ((fm.stringWidth(component.getText()) >= availWidth) || (fm.getHeight() >= availHeight))) {
        newFont = oldFont.deriveFont(--size);
        fm = component.getFontMetrics(newFont);
    }

    component.setFont(newFont);
}
```

Also you can try to find the `size` variable like a binary search rather than decrementing one by one. For range `[9 - size=min(width, height)]` first try `(size - 9)/2`, if it fits search in range `[(size - 9)/2 - size]`. If it does not fit search between `[9 - (size - 9)/2]`.

Here is a growing GridBagLayout alternative:

```
private TestClass() {
    panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    displayLabel = new JLabel("some text goes here");
    displayLabel.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 9));
    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gc.weightx = 1;
    gc.weighty = 1;
    panel.add(displayLabel, gc);

    panel.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            scale(displayLabel);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi hkn and thanks for time spent and the answer. Unfortunately your solution will not suffice. I've actually tried replacing my original while loop with a binary search and as well as an algorithm which will use the last font size and try to increase it/decrease it until it fits, in order to make it more efficient, but the issue still reproduces.

Comment: Can you try the code which calculates the values only once?

Comment: I did. I've also updated the scale method with the one that I'm currently using. Please take a look. Once again, the problem seems to be with MigLayout (fill + grow), replacing it with BorderLayout it works smooth

Comment: As as said before, changing the LayoutManager for both Panels to another one (non MigLayout) would be a valid workaround. However, in my case, I really would rather not do it because all of the further implications.